# Serving static files in "storybook js"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I am using storybook documentation and couldn't load images from assets folder. As documentations says: "if you are using a custom Webpack config, you need to add the file-loader into your custom Webpack config" - and my webpack.config file looks like:

```
const path = require('path');


 module.exports = ({ config }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    });
 config.module.rules.push({
   test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
   use: [
     {
       loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
     },
   ],
 });
 config.module.rules.push({
   test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
   use: [
     {
       loader: 'file-loader',
     },
    ]
  },);

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx')


  return config;
};
```

package.json:

```
"react": "^16.10.1",
"react-dom": "^16.10.1",
"typescript": "^3.6.3",
"@storybook/react": "^5.2.1",
"@types/storybook__react": "^4.0.2",
"file-loader": "^4.2.0"
```

This is after yarn storybook [image: webpack-debug]

seems like something is missing from storybooks documentation, or I am doing something wrong :? thank you whoever can help me out with this problem. ^_^

Comment: I fixed the error by adding custom.d.ts file with code below:
        declare module "*.svg" {
          const content: any;
          export default content;
        } 
Error has gone, but icon still not showing :/ any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone come across same problem, try code below (I am using: storybook, react - without create react app, typescript) :

First issue was about typescript and here is what worked for me: 
I created custom.d.ts file in root folder and put this code inside:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

declare module "svg-inline-react"
```

Then I add this file inside tsconfig.json like this:

```
"files": [
  "./custom.d.ts"
],
```

After that, error - "could't find imageName.svg" disappeared, but svg-inline-react still didn't show icon, now problem was inside 'webpack.config.js' file, fixed code is written below.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = ({ config }) => {

  config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map( data => {
    // This overrides default svg rouls of storybook, and after that we can use 
   //svg-inline-loader.
    if (/svg\|/.test( String( data.test ) ))
      data.test = /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani) 
 (\?.*)?$/;
    return data;
  });

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      });
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
        },
      ],
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
      loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
    });

    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx')
    return config;
};
```

^_^

Answer (score 11):

### Configuring the static folder in the storybook-start script worked for me:

#### Documentation: [Static Files Via Directory](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/serving-static-files/#2-via-a-directory)

> You can also configure a directory (or a list of directories) for
>   searching static content when you are starting Storybook. You can do
>   that with the -s flag.

```js
//package.json
{
"scripts": {
    "start-storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public -p 9001"
  }
}
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have CRA project with file-loader:
Error: ....png falls outside of the project src/ director

Comment: @Luke359, you might have to follow the `create-react-app` documentation for their recommendation for static files.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I've already tried this https://gist.github.com/shilman/bc9cbedb2a7efb5ec6710337cbd20c0c

Step by step, no errors, except for that dammned image

Comment: @Luke359, you can clone this repository https://github.com/appsparkler/reacts.  Go to the **luke/storybook** branch, do a `yarn install` and `yarn start`.  There is an **Image Story** and you can verify the image rendered from public folder.

Comment: Thanks for it. Actually I found the issue, the import paths were importing from localhost/public but the build only contained the contents from public folder so to access public/images I had only to write images

Answer (score 3):

### To fix that:

I have the following folder structure

```sh
# root_folder

.storybook/
src/
package.json
...
...
```

And my images folder lives inside `src/resources/images/my_image.jpg`

I fixed that by adding the `-s ./` as of the following

```
"storybook": "start-storybook -s ./ -p 9001"
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I already fix that issue and wrote answer myself, above. Thank one more time.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Storybook (version 7 at the time of writing) using `staticDirs` configuration element is the recommended way. Example:

```
module.exports = {
   staticDirs: ['../public', './static']
};
```

I've stumbled upon this on upgrading from storybook version 6 to version 7, previously I was using the `-s` in the CLI, which is now deperecated.

[Source](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/images-and-assets)